# Invoke a Link in custom size browser

Tags: javascript

I want to have a link or something which could be inserted in an email/forum etc. It's a typical url. But I would like that link to be opened in a custom sized new browser window ( say 800 x 600 ) . It sounds weird, but that is the requirement. Can it be achieved somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Oh please don't. New windows are annoying. New windows that are the wrong size are annoying. New windows that don't fit on my screen are excessively irritating (I'm not the only person to own a netbook with an 800x480 screen).

Comment: even I don like that. But difficult to convince managers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This is how we could kinda achieve this. Let that link be a normal link. It would contain the custom code to create a desired popup on invocation. But the issue is popup blocker in browser. But they somehow liked it.So basically a page opens up which launches the popup without user interference.

Answer (score 0):

In an email?

You can't. Email clients insane enough to execute JavaScript are all by unheard of.

In a forum?

Assuming you aren't the administrator of it, you can't. Forums insane enough to encourage XSS attacks are, again, all but unheard of.